# Can't filter based on boolean array on numpy array python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I have this simple code in python:

```
 >>> farray
 array([ 34.646433,  34.642292,  34.645295,  34.645938,  34.647517,
    34.646254,  34.640245])
 >>> is_ok
 0    False
 1    False
 2    False
 3    False
 4    False
 5    False
 6    False
 dtype: bool
```

Now if I do this:

```
 >>>farray[is_ok]
array([ 34.646433,  34.646433,  34.646433,  34.646433,  34.646433,
    34.646433,  34.646433])
```

When I tested my code it worked and the output was []. However I've used it on a different machine and it doesn't work. From what I've seen, both machines have 3.6.3 python. I also get a warning:

```
D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:1: FutureWarning: in 
the future, boolean array-likes will be handled as a 
boolean array index
"""Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
```

Can someone please explain to me what's happening? I'm not very familiar with python.

Comment: Did you check for version differences in Pandas and NumPy between environments?

Comment: Can you show exactly the code you are using and provide the `numpy` version?

Comment: Yes, looks like I had different numpy versions even though I had updated ... needed to restart the kernel. I sure feel stupid now, thanks for the support

Answer (score 0):

Different numpy versions, needed to restart kernel after updating